# Mistake when solving linear equation (3 variables, moving one to the right side)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I tried to solve an exercise from Khan Academy's ["More in linear independence"](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/linear-independence/v/more-on-linear-independence), but ran into a strange mistake. The exercise is:

$$2c_1 + 3c_2 +  c_3 = 0 \\
   c_1 + 2c_2 + 2c_3 = 0$$

After multiplying row 2 with -1 and adding the two, I get to

$$c_1 + c_2 - c_3 = 0$$

It therefore seemed obvious to me that

$$c_1 + c_2 = c_3$$

... and a valid solution could be $c_1 = 1, c_2 = 2, c_3 = 3$, which obviously doesn't hold. However, the solution given in class ($c_1 = 4, c_2 = 3, c_3 = -1$) would fit and be a valid solution. I also understand that there must be an issue with the sign, but would love to understand what the rule is I broke to not make this mistake in the future.

Comment: The solution given c1=4, c2=3 and c3=-1 doesn't fit the equations provided. c1=4, c2=-3 and c3=1 does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $c_1+c_2=c_3$ is *necessary*, but not sufficient to yield a solution. You still have to satisfy $c_1+2c_2+2c_3=0$.

This binds another variable: $c_1+2c_2+2(c_1+c_2)=0$ becomes $3c_1+4c_2=0$.

You may wonder why I took the second equation. Well, it's the same: if you consider $2c_1+3c_2+c_3=0$, you get $2c_1+3c_2+c_1+c_2=0$, so $3c_1+4c_2=0$. It's irrelevant which one you take.

Comment: Thanks a lot - can you give a hint as to how to detect whether sth is sufficient, besides testing it in the original problem? Or is that the way to test for it?

Comment: @idledowdy I'd use a more systematic approach, such as Gaussian elimination. Anyway, speaking generally, if you have two equations, you should expect two unknowns to be bound.